# Internet Explorer Not Showing Images on Webpage

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

I built a website that is functional on firefox, chrome and safari, but when I open it in Internet Explorer nothing shows up.  What am I doing wrong?  It's several different pictures, but the markup for one is as follows:

```
<div id="thepic">
<img src="images/chairs.png" alt="" height="600px" width=""> <br />
</div><!-----------------CLOSES THE PIC------------>

#thepic{
float:left;
margin-top:190px;   
margin-left:-100px;
}
```

Comment: That is not enough information to tell you what is wrong. You do have invalid HTML though `<img alt="" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE requires a defined `width` on `<img>` and expects only integers.

`<img src="images/chairs.png" alt="" height="600" width="600">`

Then in your CSS:

```
#thepic{
 float:left;
 margin-top:190px;   
 margin-left:-100px;
}

#thepic img {
 height: 600px; /* force height to 600px */
 width: auto; /* auto calculates the width ratio using 600px height */
}
```

Comment: Why are you giving the image a height / width via HTML tag AND CSS?

Comment: Both are required in HTML markup for IE browser. I *think* OP wants to scale the image down to 600px height and respective width (without defining the width numerically). CSS allows us to do this and override the width value in HTML.

Comment: I have tried it here in IE10 with an image where I only set the height attribute of the image (so no CSS and no width) and it still works...

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes - I'm talking about XHTML in old IE (like 7...8..)